# Javascript parseInt not working on a string, trying to get an integer from an HTML value

Tags: javascript, parseint

I am making a basic game, and I have a tile system that I'm using.  Each tile has an ID of "tileX", where X is a number (ex. tile1).  I have a function as follows:

```
window.onclick = function() {
    var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY,
    elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y).id;
    document.getElementById("tileTell").value = elementMouseIsOver;
    console.log(elementMouseIsOver);
    console.log(typeof(elementMouseIsOver));
    elementMouseIsOver = parseInt(elementMouseIsOver);
    console.log(elementMouseIsOver);
    console.log(typeof(elementMouseIsOver));
}
```

Line 4 of code there fills in an input field so I can visually see which tile I've clicked (I'm using this to make sure things are working properly and so I can find the tiles I need).  That works fine.  On line 5 when I do a `console.log`, it gives me the proper ID, and verifies that it is a `string`.

After that I want to reset the `elementMouseIsOver` variable to be an integer, so if the ID was `tile1` I would expect the new result to be `1`.  But when I look at it in the console, I get `NaN`.  And then when I check the type of it immediately after that, I get `number`.

The `parseInt` does not seem to be working properly, what am I doing wrong?  I need to use the ID names of each tile for mathematical operations so this is vital to my game.  I know it's probably a really dumb mistake but I am completely at a loss...

Comment: `"1"` might be an integer string that can be `parseInt`'d, but `"tile1"` definitely is not. Try `parseInt(elementMouseIsOver.slice(4), 10)`

Answer (score 4):

If you want `parseInt()` to work on strings in the way you're using it, it has to start with a digit; in your case, it starts with alphabetical characters, and so (with an implicit radix of 10) it will rightfully return `NaN`.

You could get the number out by using a generic method:

```
var num = +(elementMouseIsOver.match(/\d+/) || [])[0];
```

It matches the first group of digits it can find and then uses the unary plus operator to cast it into an actual number value. If the string doesn't contain any digits, it will yield `NaN`.

In your particular case, you could also apply `parseInt()` on the part that immediately follows `"tile"`:

```
var num = +elementMouseIsOver.substr(4);
```

Answer (score 2):

`NaN` is correct.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

Nothing parsed successfully.

**EDIT**

You could accomplish what you want by removing the non-numeric characters from the string, assuming you'll always have a string+integer as the ID. Try this:

```
parseInt(elementMouseIsOver.replace(/[^\d]/,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

The typeof of a NaN is number.

Use `isNaN()` to test if a value is `NaN` or **N**ot **a** **Number**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

You could also use the `Number()` cast instead of `parseInt()`.

Comment: `Number("tile1")` also yields `NaN`.

Comment: it have same behavior as parseInt

Comment: you can parse to number "texts" but numbers in form of string.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Use something like 
elementMouseIsOver = (typeof elementMouseIsOver==='string' ? 1 : elementMouseIsOver)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the "tile" string first, so it can properly parse the value:

```
elementMouseIsOver = parseInt(elementMouseIsOver.substring("tile".length));
```

- `.substring("tile".length)` returns a substring starting with the character after "tile" (position 4 in the string, count starts at 0), resulting in only the number of the ID (as a string).

**fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rk96uygd/**

Answer (score 0):

you trying to parseInt on a element ID that is non-numeric, when parse fail it will return `NaN (*or not a number*)`

```
elementMouseIsOver = parseInt(elementMouseIsOver);
```

moreover, your `elementMouseIsOver` is an `ID` of control, I don't think `.value` can get the value of control

```
elementMouseIsOver = document.elementFromPoint(x, y).id;
```

Comment: `NaN` doesn't represent `null`; `NaN` is a Number type whereas `null` is a Null type and its representative value.